# Minimize the cost of a 3 cubic unit volume box, given the price of each of six sides per unit area

Tags: calculus, optimization, solution-verification

I was wondering if anyone could help verify my answer of a question, or if it is incorrect to maybe let me know my mistake?

The questions asks to minimize the cost of a 3 cubic unit volume rectangle , where the price per unit of both the  front and back side cost 2 , both the top and bottom cost 2, and the other two sides cost 8.

What I have done;

Let C denote the cost. we have

$$C=2(2xy)+2(2yz)+2(8xz)=4xy+4yz+16xz$$ , which I want to minimize with restraint $$z=\frac{3}{xy}$$

ie, $$C=4xy+\frac{12}{x}+16x\frac{3}{xy}=4xy+\frac{12}{x}+\frac{48}{y}$$

$$C_x=4y-\frac{12}{x^2}$$ setting to zero $$\rightarrow 4yx^2=12$$

$$C_y=4x-\frac{48}{y^2}$$ setting to zero $ \rightarrow 4xy^2=48 $, solving equations simultaneously to get $$xy(y-4x)=0 $$ $$ xy \ne 0 \rightarrow y=4x$$

Now can I just plug in to any of my other expressions to obtain the values, for example, that would give $x$= cube root of 3/4 * I cant get the expression in latex to work well,

from there I can solve y using that it is $4x$ and thus $z$.

Is that a correct approach though. does that value make sense ? Thanks. I really do appreciate it.

Comment: Why a vote down.. I litterly followed the rules and posted all that I tried with my own work. What does a post need?

Comment: [A good title](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959#10144), for one thing.

Comment: @Woodface  Is that really a reason to downvote? Dont you think it is more constructive to atleast comment at that, if it you were to downvote atleast let the person know to change it?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I edited your title and did _not_ downvote.

Comment: @Woodface Oh I wasn't implying that you did downvote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your equations are correct, you properly establish that $$C_x=4y-\frac{12}{x^2}$$ $$C_y=4x-\frac{48}{y^2}$$ and you want these two expressions to be simultaneously equal to $0$.

What you did is perfectly correct; to me, may be the small problem (which does not change the result) is that you started using $C_x=C_y$ while I would have prefered $C_x=C_y=0$.

Eliminate for example $y$ from $C_x=0$ (you could also eliminate $x$ from $C_y$); this gives $y=\frac{3}{x^2}$; pluging this result in $C_y=0$ gives $C_y=4 x-\frac{16 x^4}{3}=0$ which, excluding $x=0$, gives $$1-\frac{4 x^3}{3}=0$$ the only real root of which being $$x=\sqrt[3]\frac 34$$ as you found (there two complex roots I suppose you do not care about). From there, you get $y$, $z$ and $C$ (you can notice from $y=\frac{3}{x^2}$ and $z=\frac{3}{xy}$ that $z=x$ which make $C=8 x (2 x+y)$ easier to compute).

Comment: Yes I am not looking for complex roots , or should I? would that be physically possible though?

Comment: So, it is fine ! You did well !

Comment: Thank you sir! and lastly, which are you saying assuming by calculations are correct? is there any way you could possibly check and if its wrong just  let me know and il work it again? thanks